# print a div tag using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have html content in div tag. I want to print this content by vb.net code. Anyone can help me ? how to erite a code in vb.net web application for print the content?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Response.Write("Your div content goes here")

End Sub
```